# wso2 esb mtom - Error in extracting message properties - Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence

Tags: character-encoding, wso2, cxf, mtom

I have a wso2esb proxy that calls a Cxf SOAP WebService (deployed on Tomcat) and also a REST api that calls the same Cxf WS (with the payload transformation request: JSON->XML and response: XML->JSON).
The service is annotated with @MTOM. 
All works fine, but when the response coming from the service contains data  with special characters (ex: à è ì ò ù) then wso2 log this error:

```
[2015-09-10 17:32:55,123] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} -  Content-Type:multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; boundary="uuid:5262f134-0ff6-4c39-bcd7-682360f77566"; start="<root.message@cxf.apache.org>"; start-info="application/soap+xml",Date:Thu, 10 Sep 2015 15:32:55 GMT,Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1,Transfer-Encoding:chunked, Unexpected error sending message back {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error in extracting message properties
        at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartSender.invoke(RampartSender.java:76)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:426)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:163)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:321)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:94)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:268)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:488)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:170)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:225)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.rampart.RampartException: Error in extracting message properties
        at org.apache.rampart.RampartMessageData.<init>(RampartMessageData.java:414)
        at org.apache.rampart.MessageBuilder.build(MessageBuilder.java:61)
        at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartSender.invoke(RampartSender.java:65)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Error in converting SOAP Envelope to Document; nested exception is:
        org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,278]
Message: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.
        at org.apache.rampart.util.Axis2Util.getDocumentFromSOAPEnvelope(Axis2Util.java:149)
        at org.apache.rampart.RampartMessageData.<init>(RampartMessageData.java:268)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,278]
Message: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.build(OMSerializableImpl.java:78)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.build(OMElementImpl.java:722)
        at org.apache.rampart.util.Axis2Util.getDocumentFromSOAPEnvelope(Axis2Util.java:84)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,278]
Message: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:596)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.next(SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.java:138)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.xop.XOPDecodingStreamReader.next(XOPDecodingStreamReader.java:181)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
        ... 25 more
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-09-10 17:32:55,125] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool} -  Uncaught exception {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool}
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,278]
Message: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.buildNext(OMElementImpl.java:653)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getFirstOMChild(OMElementImpl.java:670)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getChildren(OMElementImpl.java:352)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:553)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:555)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:555)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:555)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.internalSerialize(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:230)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serialize(OMSerializableImpl.java:125)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serialize(OMSerializableImpl.java:113)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.toString(OMElementImpl.java:988)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2847)
        at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:232)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator.getFullLogMessage(LogMediator.java:184)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator.getLogMessage(LogMediator.java:123)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator.mediate(LogMediator.java:91)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler.onFault(MediatorFaultHandler.java:85)
        at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:102)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:493)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:170)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:225)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,278]
Message: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:596)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.next(SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.java:138)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.xop.XOPDecodingStreamReader.next(XOPDecodingStreamReader.java:181)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.build(OMSerializableImpl.java:78)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.build(OMElementImpl.java:722)
        at org.apache.rampart.util.Axis2Util.getDocumentFromSOAPEnvelope(Axis2Util.java:84)
        at org.apache.rampart.RampartMessageData.<init>(RampartMessageData.java:268)
        at org.apache.rampart.MessageBuilder.build(MessageBuilder.java:61)
        at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartSender.invoke(RampartSender.java:65)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:426)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:163)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:321)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:94)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:268)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:488)
        ... 7 more
```

This error happens both for proxy and REST API.
The same request works fine if I remove @MTOM from WS.
Wso2esb and Tomcat are on the same machine with CentOS.
wso2esb4.8.1
tomcat8.0.24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after a week wasted searching an answer, i've got a solution. 
The famous error "Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence." means that an xml has enconding="UTF-8" in the prolog
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
but the content has a different encoding. When WSO2 attempts to parse the response it raises that error because of the difference between the encoding declared and the encoding of the payload. So, in the CXF webservice i've forced this encoding to the incoming and outgoing xml with
 `PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage().put(Message.ENCODING, "UTF-8");`
You can add this line in the incoming/outgoing Interceptors, if you have them, or in the handler declared in handler-chain.xml. The latter is my case.